# redis is running but I'm getting "Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused"

Tags: django, redis

I 'm using django + redis +  celery. It works: tasks are queued and executed. But every now and then I get a bunch of errors saying

> Cannot connect to redis://localhost:6379//: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused

If I check the uptime of my `redis-server` process, I see it has been up from before the errors started, so it never crashed or anything.

Any idea what's going on? what can I check to see what's happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it listening to 6379 port?

Comment: @Swagat yes most tasks are being queued and executed

Answer (score 0):

Install redis server and try again:

```
sudo apt-get install redis-server
```